# wordpress plugin- how to avoid potential overload on the server /database?

Tags: database, wordpress, httprequest, overloading

I’m using wordpress(buddypress) to build a dating website.

estimated Members -6000,estimated visitors per day 500-600.

Major part of this website will be a kind of matching questionnaire ,
each time you or other member answer a question a constantly updating list of your best matches (from all the members), will be displayed in the questionnaire page in the website .

That means a lots of **simultaneous database connections /requests**.

now I was told by a colleague that developing such questionnaire plugin for wordpress /buddypress is a big mistake.

First because processing all this data in real time, meaning answers sent to database ,compared ,calculated and send back to the page will exceed the server capacity very soon.

Second because each request Invokes loading of the whole WordPress (wp-load.php).
His solution was to manage all the calculations outside wordpress like in some kind of SOAP web service,

i ask for your advice  :

do you think there is a good chance that plugin like this will cause a problem of overload ?
how to avoid overloading in this plugin and is webservice really the solution?
creating a seperate database?

ill appreciate any help i can get thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the owner of a BuddyPress site, like yours.
I am not using this plugin, but In my site I make a lot of calculations to obtain some metrics. It is not a good option to make a calculation in real time. I prefer to make this calculations in batch mode (in cron proccess) for instance, every hour, or every 10 minutes.
If you need more help, tell me, I was working a lot in performance on BuddyPress.

Comment: that will be great thank you very much!  how can i contact you?

Comment: Sory for the delay, I did not see this comment. Please contact from my blog (menu "contacto") in this link: [http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com/](http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com/)